# Solution to nasty power-law integral $ \int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^\alpha)^8} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

$$
\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^\alpha)^8} dx
$$

with $ \alpha \gt 0$. Everything is real, and $\lambda$ is a numerical constant.

There is a nice easy solution for the case $\alpha = 2$. But I need a general solution as a function of $\alpha$. I would solve numerically, but unfortunately I require the $\alpha$ dependency for my final result.

Any pointers or advice welcome.

Comment: If you only need it numerically for various $\alpha$ then how about splitting it into two parts, making the substitution $ x \to 1/x$ in the second piece, and then expanding each as a powerseries and integrating termwise ( maybe more pieces if you ned faster convergence). Maybe the resulting series looks familiar.

Comment: Is $\alpha \geq 0$?

Comment: @jwimberley, must be bigger than $0$! I'll edit it now.

Comment: @Testcase, can you give me a bit more detail on what you're suggesting? Not sure I follow (might be my physics background).

Comment: We need $\alpha > 3/8$ for the integral to converge, I believe.

Comment: Also, rescaling $x \rightarrow \lambda^{-1/\alpha}u$ lets you get rid of $\lambda$ in the integral: $\lambda^{-3/\alpha} \int_0^{\infty} u^2/(1+u^\alpha)^8 du$.

Comment: The change of variables $v=\frac{1}{1+\lambda x^\alpha}$, assuming $\lambda>0$ will produce simple expression in terms of the Beta function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t= \lambda x^\alpha$
$$
I= 
\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^\alpha)^8} dx=
\frac1{\alpha\lambda^{\frac{3-\alpha}{\alpha}} }\int^\infty_0\frac{t^{\frac{3-\alpha}{\alpha}} }{(1+t)^8} dt
$$
Then, apply the recursion
$$
\int^\infty_0\frac{t^b}{(1+t)^n} dt=\frac b{n-1}
\int^\infty_0\frac{t^{b-1}}{(1+t)^{n-1}} dt
$$
along with $\int^\infty_0\frac{t^{s-1}}{1+t} dt=\frac\pi{\sin{\pi s}}$ to obtain
$$I = \frac{\pi(1-\frac3 a)(1-\frac3{2a})(1-\frac3{3a})(1-\frac3{4a})(1-\frac3{5a})(1-\frac3{6a})(1-\frac3{7a})}{a\lambda^{\frac{3-a}{a}}\sin\frac{3\pi}{a} }
$$

Comment: Thanks! Just to double check, 'a' in the final line is $\alpha$, right?

Comment: @FairyLiquid - correct,  easier to type

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One approach might be to write the integral as
$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^{\alpha})^8} dx =  \int_0^1\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^{\alpha})^8 dx} +  \int_1^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^{\alpha})^8} dx$$

In the second of the integrals on the right make the substitution $u=1/x$ giving us
$$ \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^{\alpha})^8} dx =  \int_0^1\frac{x^2}{(1+\lambda x^{\alpha})^8} dx -  \int_0^1\frac{1}{u^2(1+\lambda u^{-\alpha})^8} \frac{-1}{u^2}du$$
(this caluculation should probably be checked carefully...).
Now we can use the expansion
$$\frac{1}{(1+\lambda x^{\alpha})^8} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\ldots (n+6)}{2 \cdots 7} \lambda^n x^{\alpha n}$$
which essientially arise from differentiating the usual geometric sum 7 times and inserting $(-\lambda x^\alpha)$ as the variable (again, you should check the details, this was litterally done on the back of an envelope).Using this the first of the integrals above can be written as power-series and integrated termwise, and a similar trick will apply ot the second one after some rewriting.

Note that if $\lambda$ is larger than $1$ or $\alpha$ is sufficiently small (less than 1/2) you will run into issues of convergence which you should probably give some thought to (the first one doesnt seem that serious, as for the second one I am not sure your original integral is even well-defined for $\alpha<1/2$). Anyway this could be a start.

Comment: If $\alpha > 1/2$, then writing the second integrand as $u^{8\alpha - 4}/(u^\alpha + \lambda)^8$ keeps all the calculations finite. $3/8 < \alpha < 1/2$ is more annoying as you have an integrable divergence at the origin.

Comment: Thank you! I've followed this through to something that looks nice and manageable!

Comment: @fairyliquid You are welcome, but both Oliver Diaz remark and Quanto s solution are a lot smarter and cleaner than working with series.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, transform the integral by letting $y=\lambda x^{\alpha}$, then
$$
I=\frac{1}{\alpha \lambda^{\frac{3}{\alpha}}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{\frac{3}{\alpha}-1}}{(1+y)^{8}} d y
$$

Then convert $I$ into a Beta Function by letting $z=\frac{1}{1+y}$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
I = \int_{0}^{1}z^{\left(8-\frac{3}{\alpha} \right)-1}(1-z)^{\frac{3}{\alpha}-1} d z =\frac{1}{\alpha \lambda^{\frac{3}{\alpha}}} B\left(8-\frac{3}{\alpha}, \frac{3}{\alpha}\right) =\frac{\Gamma\left(8-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)}{ \alpha \lambda^{\frac{3}{\alpha}}\Gamma(8)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the property of Gamma Function
$$
\Gamma(z+1)=z \Gamma(z),
$$

we can simplify the numerator as
$$
\begin{array}{l} \Gamma\left(8-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)=
\left(7-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(6-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(5-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(4-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(3-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)
\left(2-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \Gamma\left(1-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)
\end{array}
$$

Using the Reflection Property of Gamma Function
$$
\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)=\pi \csc (\pi z), \textrm{ where } z\not\in Z,
$$

we can now conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}I&=\frac{\left(7-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(6-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \left(5-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(4-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(3-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)
\left(2-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) \pi}{7!\alpha \lambda^{\frac{3}{\alpha}} \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi}{\alpha}\right)}\\&=\frac{\pi \displaystyle  \prod_{k=1}^{7}\left(1-\frac{3}{k \alpha}\right)}{\alpha \lambda^{\frac{3}{\alpha}} \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi}{\alpha}\right)}\end{aligned}
$$